# VueJS + VeeValidator + Multiple fields

Tags: vue.js

Versions:

- VueJs: 2.2.2
- Vee-Validate: 2.0.0-beta.25

#### Description:

I'm wondering if there's a way to have a unique validator for multiple fields?

Typically, an Address form with 1 input fot the street, 1 for the number and 1 for the city

I want to make a validation on the combination of all the elements.

I've read the documentation but I can't find an exemple that could help me for that.

Comment: One way would be to make an address component that returned a value that contained all the values and then write a custom validator for that combined value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could apply a custom validator to a custom component that contained all the fields you want to validate together. For example, you could build a `location` component (using `location` instead of `address` because `address` is an HTML5 element, and you cannot name a Vue component the same as an existing HTML element).

```
Vue.component("location", {
  props:["value"],
  template: "#location-template",
  data(){
    return {
      location: this.value
    }
  },
  methods:{
    update(){
      this.$emit('input', Object.assign({}, this.location))
    }
  },
})
```

Then you can build a validator for that component.

```
const locationValidator = {
  currentLocation: null,
  getMessage(field, args) {
    if (!this.currentLocation.street)
      return "Location requires a street";
    if (!this.currentLocation.street_number)
      return "Location requires a street_number";
    if (!this.currentLocation.city)
      return "Location requires a city";
  },
  validate(location, args) {
    this.currentLocation = location;

    if (!location.street || !location.street_number || !location.city)
      return false;

    return true
  }
};
```

Finally, you can pull that together in your Vue.

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    loc: {}
  },
  created(){
    this.$validator.extend("location", locationValidator)
  }
})
```

And your Vue template

```
<span v-show="errors.has('location')" style="color:red">{{ errors.first('location') }}</span>
<location v-validate="'location'" v-model="loc" data-vv-name="location"></location>
```

Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/xqWgBm?editors=1010).

Comment: Great post. This helped me a lot.